# What functions or codes require GET_TASKS permission in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

I think the GET_TASKS permission is an orphan line in my AndroidManifest.xml. I want to remove it safely. Do you know any function or code that requires this permission? Thank you.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: "GET_TASKS" permission [Allows an application to get information about the currently or recently running tasks.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the android [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

> Allows an application to get information about the currently or
>   recently running tasks.

An example is `public List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> getRecentTasks (int maxNum, int flags)` as it throws SecurityException if the caller does not hold the GET_TASKS permission.

---

Note that according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,%20int))

> This constant was deprecated in API level 21. No longer enforced.

and

> As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party
>   applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it
>   can leak personal information to the caller. For backwards
>   compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at
>   least the caller's own tasks (though see getAppTasks() for the correct
>   supported way to retrieve that information), and possibly some other
>   tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I think the code related to this permission has been removed from my app, but I would like to scan the project for these functions or codes in order to remove this permission safely.

Comment: As far as I know (and [google search for the exception](https://www.google.com/search?q="Throws+SecurityException+if+the+caller+does+not+hold+the+GET_TASKS+permission.+")) the only functions using this permission is `getRunningTasks` and `getRecentTasks` all in [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)

Comment: Notice it is deprecated in Lollipop (no longer enforced).

Comment: @idaNakav I just saw that too. Does that mean Android L doesn't check for that permission if the mentioned methods are called?

Comment: It looks to me like it no longer returns as much information as it did in prior versions, to avoid privacy leaks from document-oriented tasks in the "recents" list. Because it returns less information, perhaps it is no longer viewed as a security concern.

Answer (score -1):

```
class CheckRunningActivity extends Thread{
ActivityManager am = null;
Context context = null;

public CheckRunningActivity(Context con){
    context = con;
    am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
}

public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();

    while(true){
        // Return a list of the tasks that are currently running,
        // with the most recent being first and older ones after in order.
        // Taken 1 inside getRunningTasks method means want to take only
        // top activity from stack and forgot the olders.
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        String currentRunningActivityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

        if (currentRunningActivityName.equals("PACKAGE_NAME.ACTIVITY_NAME")) {
            // show your activity here on top of PACKAGE_NAME.ACTIVITY_NAME
        }
    }
    Looper.loop();
}
}
```